# java mysql server timeout errors with lack of activity

Tags: java

I'm not new to programming, but I am new to Java . I've been using it to write plugins for Bukkit, a Minecraft server wrapper. My issue is unrelated to that though, this is a pure java issue.

I have a bit of code to open a mysql connection when the server starts but if we ever go for a length of time without any queries being run by my code, the following error shows next time there is a query attempt:

```
09:12:58 [SEVERE] Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 74,977 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor87.newInstance(Unknown Source)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3082)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2968)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3516)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2111)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2407)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2325)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2310)
09:12:58 [SEVERE]       at me.botsko.dhmcstats.DhmcstatsPlayerListener.onPlayerJoin(DhmcstatsPlayerListener.java:48)
```

After posting for help on the Bukkit forums I tweaked my connect code, but this is essentially what I'm using now:

```
  protected void dbc(){
        java.util.Properties conProperties = new java.util.Properties();
        conProperties.put("user", "root");
        conProperties.put("password", "");
        conProperties.put("autoReconnect", "true");
        conProperties.put("maxReconnects", "3");

        try {
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/minecraft", conProperties);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.throwing("me.botsko.dhmcstats", "dbc()", e);
        }
    }
```

There is a lot better performance from the plugins, they don't die as often but I'm finding that this error still shows, and that you have to run the queries twice - once seems to re-open the connection and then the second time, the query would work.

I have a feeling this is just a problem with how I am managing the database connections but am finding few examples on the net that differ from my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If your connection to mysql is open for a long time with no activity it becomes stale, which is most probably the source of this error.

Since it does not appear you are using a connection pool (which you probably should). You can go for running a simple validation query every so ofter in order keep the connection from going stale (just setup a separate thread to run on given intervals). The validation query could be something as simple as

```
select 1
```

But a better way to do this would be to use a connection pool like [C3PO](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html) or [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/). In which case it is just a matter of configuring the validation query and this logic is already built into the pools. e.g. with DBCP you can set the [config. property](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html) `validationQuery` to be equal to `select 1` and it would take care of running the query for you on certain intervals that you can define in the config as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to manage connections in connection management pool like C3P0. Most likely you are getting connection time out. Such as `DriverManager` object could have default time out, as you didn't set it in properties.

I personally would recommend to use JDBC pool like C3P0 or some other open source jdbc pool management package.